# Email button on Extjs Toolbar

Tags: email, extjs, toolbar

I'm having trouble adding a mailto: link to a grid panel's toolbar.

I've tried modifying the object's HTML configuration & also via the handler but neither are opening the new email message.

```
{
text   : 'Support', 
html: '<a href="mailto:email@xx.com" target="_blank">Support</a>'
}


{
text   : 'Support', 
handler: function() {
   return '<a href="mailto:email@xx.com">Support</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handler:` is used to create handler function of button pressed. To make your mailto link work you should redirect to `mailto:email@xx.com` address like:

```
handler: function() {
    window.location = 'mailto:email@xx.com';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as @webbandit suggested, except I would use `window.open('mailto:address.com')`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ExtJS 4.x, you can define it in href:

```
{
    text : 'Support', 
    href : "mailto:email@xx.com"
 }
```

`hrefTarget="_blank"` is default value, but it is better if you set it to `_self`:

```
{
    text : 'Support', 
    href : "mailto:email@xx.com",
    hrefTarget: "_self"
 }
```